# Google Apps Script to allow editors to edit certain protected cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really need help for my code. What I do along with some other friends of mine is tutor as a part-time job. Every week, I create a sheet and have my friends fill out columns based on which group of people they tutored. Because sometimes some of my friends mistakenly fill out the wrong columns, I protect the columns and allow them to edit their respective columns by protecting every cell that they're not supposed to fill out. Because this is too tedious to do every week, I wanted to write a code instead so that when I run it it will see which editor is accessing the sheet and protect every other cell except the ones they're supposed to edit. Below is a similar code that I am working on that I can't make work. Cell, cell1 and cell2 represents three different groups of people that are tutored with each listing 1 email except cell2 which consist of two emails. These emails represent the editors (that tutor their respective group of people) who input data to their respective column. Range, range1 and range2 consists of cells that the tutors need to fill out. I have little to no knowledge for coding and this is what I can muster based on what I can find or learn. I really appreciate it if someone can help me edit my code as I don't know what to do.

```
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test 3");
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var cell = source.getRange("A6").getValue();
  var cell1 = source.getRange("C6").getValue();
  var cell2 = source.getRange("E6:E7").getValue();
  var range = ss.getRange('H5:H20');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('J5:J20');
  var range2 = ss.getRange('L5:L20');

  if (cell == email) {

    // Remove protection if cell 'A6' is email@gmail.com
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  protection.remove();
   } 
  }else {

    // Protect range H5:H20 if cell 'A6' is not email@gmail.com
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    Logger.log

    }

  if (cell1 == email) {

    // Remove protection if cell 'C6' is email1@gmail.com
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  protection.remove();

   } 
  }else {

    // Protect range H5:H20 if cell 'C6' is not email1@gmail.com
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    Logger.log
    }
  if (cell2 == email) {

    // Remove protection if cell 'C6' is email2@gmail.com
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  protection.remove();

   } 
  }else {

    // Protect range H5:H20 if cell 'C6' is not email2@gmail.com
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    Logger.log
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue you have? (You should describe, in detail, the errors you are receiving). I recommend reviewing the differences between installed and simple triggers (including what constitutes a simple trigger).

Comment: Hi tehhowch first of all thanks for asking. I keep on getting an error in my code if (cell == Logger.log(email)). I don't know what's the problem and not sure how to fix it. I made this code based on what I found in google script references. I only have some experience coding in Python and this is my first attempt on Apps Scripts so I'm not sure how to implement a trigger or do anything else. I will do some research but I do plan to take my time and learn to script when I'm more free.

Comment: I strongly recommend you review the API reference documentation for each of the methods you use, such that you could explain what each step of each line of your script is doing. In the line you reference, for example, explain what each word means and does, and how the meaning of the line changes if it is removed. You don't need to explain that to us -- explaining it to yourself or a nearby inanimate object should be sufficient. To start, `Logger.log` accesses a method of the `Logger` class that writes its arguments to an internal datastore and returns `void` (in Python terms, `None`).

Comment: I will try and do my best. Thanks.

Comment: I can't quite grasp exactly what your problem is, but the calls to Logger.log are incorrect. You need to pass [an argument to the log function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object)). It should read something like: Logger.log('I was called!');

Comment: Thanks for the reply Diego. So should I just delete it? Also, I keep on getting an error for var cell for being null which I don't understand.

Comment: @Leslie be sure to review the restrictions on simple triggers, with regards to identity and methods which need authorization

Comment: Hmm I will look into that thanks tehhowch